# Select count group by day of the dateTime

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have a table `monitor` and one of its field is date of `Date` type. A sample record is like

```
id  |  date                    |  other fields.
1      2019-03-01 20:00:00 
2      2019-03-01 20:30:00 
3      2019-03-02 20:00:00
4      2019-03-01 10:00:00
```

Now, i want to count the number of records in the last five days, and return a map like:

```
day|  count
2019-03-01    3
2019-03-02    1
```

My sql is like:

```
select day(date),count(*) from monitor group by day(date);
```

So how should i construct in mysql?  Thanks.
The problem for me here is group by day of Date field,.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d'),count(*) 
from monitor 
WHERE date between DATE_SUB(NOW(), - INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND NOW()
group by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `date()` and be very careful about the `where` clause.  Do not use `now()`, because it also has a time component.

Instead:

```
select date(date), count(*)
from monitor
where date >= curdate() - interval 5 day
group by date(date);
```